# nested children router-view still calls created multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

**Scenario**: I have a parent component in which there's a router view. This parent has 2 children components, so when I go to one of the children's component, parent's created hook shouldn't be called.

**Problem:** When I go to child 1 component, parent's created hook still gets called. same happens when I go to child 2 component. Why is that? Code seems so easy.

I Appreciate it.

Parent Component:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Parent",
    created() {
      console.log("this should NOT appear on route change i.e. parent component should be rendered only once?!");
    }
  }

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>PARENT</h1>
    <hr>
    <RouterLink to="/routetest/23/profile">FIRST CHILD</RouterLink>
    <br>
    <br>
    <RouterLink to="/routetest/23/posts">SECOND CHILD</RouterLink>
    <hr>
    <RouterView />
  </div>
</template>
```

`/routetest/23/profile` component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> CH1</h1>
  </div>
</template>
</script>
```

`/routetest/23/posts` component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> CH2</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Routes:

```
{
        path: '/routetest/:id',
        component: testparent,
        children: [{
            path: 'profile',
            meta: {
              authRequired: false,
              rule: 'isAll',
            },
            component: test1
          },
          {
            path: 'posts',
            meta: {
              authRequired: false,
              rule: 'isAll',
            },
            component: test2
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: This is done so that your webpage is search engine optimized. You can either move all logic from `created()` to `mounted()` ... or, you can put a ´v-if="someBoolean"´ in your `<template>` tag ... not sure if the latter would work

Comment: doesn't make sense. mounted also gets executed whenever changing routes.

Comment: It seems actually your code works fine.. The parent's created hook gets called only once (when the parent is loaded for the first time).. check this [codesandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-gn85q).. So the cause of the problem should be somewhere else not in this code.